# jQuery not running in html file

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have several connected, external files. I tried using the shortcut of simply listing the names of the files (all are in the same folder), but only the CSS file "works" or "connects" or whatever, so I'm now using SHIFT + RMB to "copy as path." I'm editing the files in Notepad++, and opening the files in Google Chrome on Windows 7 Home Premium, 64-bit (if it makes a difference).

HTML code:

```
<html>

<head>
<link rel = "stylesheet" type = "text/css" href = "No Real Purpose.css"/>

<title>Random text</title>
</head>

<body>
<div id = "clickToHide">
Hide div
</div>

<div id = "hidable">
hidden?
</div>

<!--Script inclusion-->
<script type = "text/javascript" src = "C:\Program Files (x86)\EasyPHP5.2.10\www\JQuery Test\No Real Purpose.js"></script>
<script type = "text/javascript" src = "C:\Program Files (x86)\EasyPHP5.2.10\www\JQueryTest\jQuery.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS code:

```
div
{
     color: white;
     background-color: black;
     box-shadow: 2px 2px black;
     height: 100px;
     width: 100px;
     padding: 3px;
     margin: 5px;
}

#hidable
{
    color: black;
    background-color: yellow;
    box-shadow: 2px 2px black;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    padding: 3px;
    margin: 5px;
}
```

jQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('clickToHide').click(function()
    {
        $('#hidable').slideToggle('fast');
    });
});
```

Where have I gone wrong?

EDIT: These are NOT posted online, they are stored locally on my computer. I'm simply trying to test my knowledge of jQuery. There are no servers!

Comment: Check your console. Make sure the files are really being included. If they are, they're probably throwing some sort of error which is causing execution to stop.

Comment: `src = "C:\Program Files` That is extremely wrong.  You need to reference a path on the server.

Comment: Server? These are local files, they aren't posted online.

Comment: When you open this html file on Chrome, what path do you see in the address bar? Does it start with 'http://'? If so, then 'C:\...' is wrong.

Comment: I see: **file:///C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/EasyPHP5.2.10/www/JQuery%20Test/No%20Real%20Purpose.html** in the address bar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your issue is this:

If your `JQueryTest` folder is at root then this should work.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/JQueryTest/jQuery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/JQueryTest/No Real Purpose.js"></script>
                           //--------^^^^^^^^^^------Your folder reference
```

here order matters jquery should be loaded before your `doc ready` call script.

Answer (score 2):

```
use this to load jquery 

<script     type="text/javascript"src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('clickToHide').click(function()
```

You haven't put a `#` before `clickToHide` so jQuery thinks you are looking for an element called clickToHide, stick a `#` in (`#clickToHide`) and see if it works.

Edit: Also, try to avoid spaces in file names, it may or may not matter here, but its bad practice and you should avoid it if you can. `No Real Purpose.css` could become `NoRealPurpose.css`

Comment: Stupid mistake :-P No, that didn't do it.

Answer (score 1):

#### Is it a typo or you missed a `#`

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('clickToHide').click(function()
------^ here?
    {
        $('#hidable').slideToggle('fast');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use relative or absolute path from server (EasyPHP emulate an Apache server), not local path from your computer:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="No_Real_Purpose.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jQuery.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to your lack of a "#" in your click() event for "clickToHide", you're also using Windows-style path formatting, which won't work.

Change your `C:\...` references to something like `/JQueryTest/NoRealPurpose.js` (the leading "/" is your web root).

It's also good to avoid using spaces in file names. Having spaces can confuse web servers and cause unexpected issues when you go from your development environment to production.

Comment: As his css link suggest, correct relative path is: NoRealPurpose.js

Comment: @roasted - Or his CSS code could be completely wrong, too, given the number of other mistakes.

Comment: <<but only the CSS file "works">> Thats why i was thinking about his site index file was in JQuery Test folder, but rereading OP question, i think you are correct.

Comment: The CSS code is linking up fine. I just can't get jQuery up and running.

Comment: @roasted - Ah, ok. I missed that part.

Answer (score 1):

Try including the JavaScript files in the head section of your html. Also, use relative paths instead of absolute: When you are using a platform like EasyPHP or xampp, you can usually access your local server by entering "http://localhost" in your web browser's bar.

In this case you would open your document by entering "localhost/JQueryTest/" (I assume your html document is placed in that folder, please also note that you have different paths for each JavaScript file, one reads \JQueryTest\ whereas the other one has a space), and the relative paths would be simply "jQuery.js".

Update: Also, as others have noted, avoid spaces when possible and check your jQuery syntax. A quick way to tell if jQuery loaded would be:

```
$(document).ready( function(){
    alert("Hey cruel world!");
});
```